# CRM 2013 Migraton: How to detect CRM 4 javascript

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I am getting following error while migrating CRM 4 database to cRM 2013 via CRM 2011.
"Setup has detected that there are customizations or solutions that are using the Microsoft Dynamics CRM 4.0 (2007) endpoint. This feature will no longer be supported in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013."
CRM was earlier developed by another vendor, so I need to find this javascript.Is there any tool or method to find out about this javascipt of CRM 4 which needs to be migrated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Custom Code Validation Tool released by Microsoft. It will tell you the web resources not compatible with CRM 2013

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30151